# No emergency alerts on iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications

I have "Emergency Alerts" enabled on my iPhone, but I do not receive alerts on it. Emergency alerts are enabled, but Amber alerts are off. I know that some alerts have gone out today because I have an older iPhone that doesn't have phone service but which does still receive emergency alerts. What do I need to do to get alerts on my regular phone? I tried turning them off and back on, but it didn't help.

The phone that doesn't get emergency alerts is an iPhone 6 using T-Mobile (USA) and running iOS 9.3.2. The one that does get alerts is an iPhone 4s running iOS 8.something, formerly used on AT&T and T-Mobile, but which doesn't have any current mobile service. Both phones connect to wifi at my house, if that matters.

Comment: If both iPhones are signed-in with your Apple ID, could the 4S be responding in place if the 6?  I don't have emergency alerts turned on so I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple support suggested the following:

1. Disable emergency alerts
2. Reboot the phone
3. Re-enable alerts.

This worked. I don't know why I wasn't getting them, but I get them now.

Comment: This just worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think so you need to update the iOS version in the software update setting, I have looked at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_9) section of iOS version but couldn't find if the emergency alerts have been even added to update. In the Wikipedia section of iOS 9.3, it highlights(Yellow Color) that the update has been discontinued. I also think that iMessage should be updated on your iPhone. Other than that, I couldn't find any answers since I searched over T-mobile website and it does say "iPhone 6". I prefer calling the carrier service provider to giving more insight on how to solve the problem. Also restart your phone, to get the settings applied. If you still can't get the emergency alert, please refer to the Google Docs that I created, which allows the user from United States and Canada to get wireless emergency alerts(EAS & Alert Ready). The document will be updated weekly/monthly and it consists of two pages. It also shows how to look at past emergency alerts in phone. Read it entirely to get the accurate information. Here is the link: [Alert Ready/EAS/WEA Notifications](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZCMu7UJXsY0kGFJCmqVs2EuJ15VpC4tzDMy3ABQ7Q5I/edit?usp=sharing).

[image: T-mobile-WEA Devices]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Comment: Hi Clement. I’m sure it’s a great resource, but it doesn’t seem to address the question here, of how to make sure that an iPhone receives alerts when they’re sent out.

Answer (score -2):

I just found out if your iPhone or iPad is on mute and even though the alerts are on you won’t get them